# Espressioni colloquiali per esprimere il dover assumersi un problema o una situazione fastidiosa, spiacevole o imbarazzante

Tags: idioms, phrase-request, colloquial

Mi piacerebbe sapere se esistono espressioni colloquiali per esprimere il fatto di dover assumersi un problema o una situazione o obbligo fastidioso, spiacevole o imbarazzante.

In [questa domanda](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/33168/), per esempio, si trova una locuzione colloquiale in castigliano per indicare questa idea, "comerse un marrón", che si potrebbe tradurre letteralmente come "mangiarsi un marrone". Può anche essere "comerse el marrón" se ci si riferisce a un problema determinato (il problema o la situazione fastidiosa sarebbe "el marrón").

Ecco [un esempio di uso che ho trovato su Google Libri](https://books.google.es/books?id=MYktciPajZYC&pg=PA95&dq=%22se+ha+comido+el+marr%C3%B3n%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj795jf5sDqAhXMxYUKHT3lB50Q6AEwAXoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22se%20ha%20comido%20el%20marr%C3%B3n%22&f=false) (grassetto mio):

> Doña Elodia, tiene cuerda
> para rato, y mi vecino **se ha comido el marrón** de cuidarla por ser hijo único, soltero y la tira de raro.

La frase fa riferimento al vicino del narratore che ha dovuto assumersi la responsabilità di vivere con sua madre per potersi prendere cura di lei, una signora anziana chiamata *doña Elodia* descritta nel testo come una vecchia fissata come non c'è nessun'altra al mondo. Quindi, questo vicino "se ha comido el marrón" di dover fare questo.

Faccio altri esempi. A causa di un errore, in un negozio o azienda si è fatto con un cliente qualcosa che non si dovrebbe aver fatto. Qualcuno deve parlare con il cliente per spiegargli cos'è successo. Si tratta di una situazione imbarazzante. Della persona che lo fa, che, per giunta, non ha nessuna responsabilità in questo errore, si può affermare che "se come el marrón".

Anche in un negozio o in un'azienda  potrebbe darsi la situazione di un cliente che arriva molto arrabbiato, gridando in modo molto gradevole. Qualche responsabile parla con lui per cercare di calmarlo. Di questa persona si potrebbe dire che "se ha comido el marrón".

Ci sono espressioni colloquiali in italiano per comunicare questa stessa idea?

Ho fatto l'esempio dell'espressione "comerse  el/un marrón", ma in spagnolo ci sono anche altre espressioni che si potrebbero usare per esprimere più o meno la stessa idea. Il problema o la situazione fastidiosa e di difficile soluzione può venire chiamato "la patata caliente", soprattutto quando qualcuno, sottraendosi alla sua responsabilità, lo scarica su un'altra persona.
Se si tratta di una situazione o problema che si prolunga nel tempo, può essere anche chiamato "una/la cruz". Quindi, nella prima situazione, si potrebbe dire, per esempio, "el hijo carga con la cruz de vivir con doña Elodia" o "vivir con doña Elodia es una cruz para su hijo". Quando qualcuno ha risolto il problema che dovrebbe essere la responsabilità di un altro si può dire di questa persona che "ha sacado las castañas del fuego" all'altra.

Per questa ragione chiedo "espressioni", al plurale, perché immagino che anche in italiano accada lo stesso.

Comment: "Prendersi la patata bollente" o "rimanere col cerino in mano" sono le prime che mi vengono in mente.

Comment: Perfetto, @RiccardoDeContardi, ma dovresti scriverlo in una risposta.

Comment: Mi dispiace: mi sono accorta che la domanda non si capiva del tutto bene senza porre un esempio.

Comment: "Mettere la testa sul ceppo"?

Comment: Nel caso specifico che citi, puoi dire che il vicino “*si è assunto l’onere*” di gestire la madre. Onere: *fig. Peso, incarico gravoso: assumersi un onere*. http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/onere/

Comment: @Hachi:  Veramente la domanda non voleva essere "quale espressione posso usare in questo contesto particolare?" (per questa ragione all'inizio non c'era nessun esempio). Volevo chiedere possibili espressioni per esprimere questa idea (in questo o in altri contesti). È successo che ho avuto l'impressione che la domanda non si capisse del tutto bene e, allora, ho cercato un esempio su Google Libri.

Comment: Veramente sarebbe meglio che tolga l'esempio e lasci la domanda nella sua versione iniziale?

Comment: Vedi tu, ma se il contesto è quello che descrivi forse ha più senso lasciare l’esempio che hai fatto.

Comment: @Hachi: Come ho detto, non volevo chiedere su questo contesto particolare. È il primo che ho trovato su Google Libri e che ho pensato si potesse capire. Forse dovrei aggiungere più esempi? Perché, a quanto pare, adesso la domanda è peggiore di come era all'inizio.

Comment: If fatto è che tutte le espressioni finora  citate vanno bene a seconda del contesto. Anche piccole sfumature possono fare la differenza. Io mi focalizzerei su un contesto specifico altrimenti la risposta diventa un elenco generico di espressioni simili.

Comment: @Hachi: Allora dovrei porre una domanda diversa per ogni situazione possibile che mi venga in mente. Non mi sembra sensato.

Comment: Se la domanda non è ben posta, cosa che può ben essere, questo è un argomento in più per cui sostengo che domande su espressioni colloquiali dovrebbero essere su questo sito (su altri siti dedicati alle lingue ci sono!), ma spesso [i meglio adatti per porle sono gli stessi italiani](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1429/) (domande in cui si chieda qualcosa su un'espressione colloquiale, ma certamente diverse da questa). So benissimo che molti non sono d'accordo, ma io continuo a credere che questo sito ha bisogno di domande fatte da italiofoni.

Comment: @Charo - concordo sul fatto che i “natives” debbano fare più domande, nel caso specifico però dubito che un italiano farebbe questa domanda in quanto  conosce già questi modi di dire che sono di uso comune. È più facile che la domanda arrivi da un non-native il quale ha meno famigliarità con queste espressioni.

Comment: @Hachi: Questa discussione si dovrebbe fare sul sito Meta (vedi link nel mio commento di sopra).

Comment: @Charo - ok sorry.....

Comment: Per gli ultimi esempi fatti userei il detto ***togliere le castagne dal fuoco***  cioè *procurare un vantaggio ad altri, affrontando una situazione problematica, assumendosi quindi il rischio.*  In sostanza, a chi se la vede con il cliente tocca “togliere le castagne dal fuoco” per conto di altri che sono i veri responsabili.

Comment: C'è anche l'espressione riguardante la "gatta da  pelare"

Comment: Le situazioni spinose sono chiamate a volte "gatte da pelare". "Prendere/rsi una gatta da pelare" significa assumersi un incarico difficile, "lasciare una gatta da pelare" significa scaricare ad altri.

Comment: @Hachi: Se su ELU si possono fare domande come, per esempio, [questa](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/544046/), sono ben accolte e ricevono subito molte risposte, non riesco proprio a capire perché su Italian.SE una domanda come questa si debba percepire come di poco interesse (?) o si debba focalizzare su un contesto specifico perché  "altrimenti la risposta diventa un elenco generico di espressioni simili" (secondo me, la domanda tanto focalizzata su un contesto especifico sarebbe meno utile). Un elenco di espressioni simili come risposta a questa domanda sarebbe una risposta utilissima.

Comment: @DaG: Cosa significa "mettere la testa sul ceppo"? Non sono riuscita a trovarlo da nessuna parte. (Forse questo dovrebbe essere un'altra domanda?)

Comment: Il fatto che nessuno scriva le espressioni che sono apparse nei commenti significa che non sono veramente adeguate a quello che si sta chiedendo nella domanda?

Comment: @Charo - non si citano le espressioni che appaiono nei commenti e vengono date risposte un po’ generiche perché non e chiaro cosa tu stia cercando. Espressioni in italiano da usare in contesti simili ce ne sono tante ma per avere una risposta mirata dovresti fare un esempio chiaro. Gli esempi che fai tu sono diversi e in italiano richiedono espressioni diverse anche se in spagnolo si usa soltanto “la comida del maron.“

Comment: Adesso si capisce meglio, @Hachi?

Comment: @Charo - cosa intendi per espressioni “in plurale”?

Comment: @Charo: La “testa sul ceppo” la mette chi, volontariamente o costretto dalle circostanze, è la vittima o il capro espiatorio di qualche situazione, con ovvio riferimento figurato al fatto di offrirsi alla scure del boia. Cercando appunto "testa sul ceppo" si trova qualche esempio di uso. Mi sembra abbastanza vicino come significato al _marrón_ di cui si diceva.

Comment: Ah, grazie, @DaG! Mi dispiace però che tutte queste espressioni che sono apparse nei commenti non siano raccolte in una risposta (secondo Hachi dovuto a che la domanda non si capisce, ma io non so più cosa fare per migliorarla).

Comment: @Charo: Io trovo che si capisca benissimo. Intanto trasformo il mio commento in una risposta.

Answer (score 2):

Prendersi (o abbracciarsi) la croce

come spiegato [sul dizionario del corriere.it](https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-modi-di-dire/C/croce.shtml);

riporto 2 esempi:

[tratto da "Soffia forte il vento nel cuore di mio figlio" di Carolina Bocca](https://books.google.it/books?id=5IbPDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT123&dq=%22si%20%C3%A8%20preso%20la%20croce%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjmOeZy9LqAhUPDOwKHd2eBcMQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22si%20%C3%A8%20preso%20la%20croce%22&f=false)

> ... dobbiamo ringraziare tutti Seba, che si è preso la croce sulle spalle per consentirci di raggiungere questo traguardo insperato.

[tratto da "I padroni delle città" di Curzio Maltese](https://books.google.it/books?id=TDPX4_m_IMoC&pg=PA54&dq=%22si%20%C3%A8%20preso%20la%20croce%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjmOeZy9LqAhUPDOwKHd2eBcMQ6AEwAXoECAAQAg#v=onepage&q=%22si%20%C3%A8%20preso%20la%20croce%22&f=false)

> ... consigliere di Enrico Letta, che si è preso la croce di trattare con il governo e i creditori ... per evitare la totale bancarotta ...

Comment: Grazie, @Nicola. Esiste anche nella variante "caricarsi la croce" che era stata suggerita in un commento (che è sparito)?

Answer (score 1):

Una espressione che ormai non usa più nessuno è "fare il Pietro Micca".

Significa farsi carico di una impresa difficile e/o pericolosa, spesso perché la persona che avrebbe dovuto farlo non è disponibile.

Da [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pietro_Micca):

> La cronaca di Giuseppe Maria Solaro della Margarita [6] narra che i
> due soldati sentirono dei colpi di arma da fuoco e capirono che non
> avrebbero resistito a lungo: decisero così di far scoppiare una carica
> di polvere nera precedentemente collocata in una nicchia nella parete
> della scala, allo scopo di provocarne il crollo e non consentire il
> passaggio ai nemici.
>
> All'esplosivo era applicato un tratto di miccia a rapida combustione
> ma, per dare il tempo a Pietro Micca e al suo commilitone di porsi in
> salvo, era necessario collegare a questa una miccia a lenta
> combustione. Ciò era compito dell'altro soldato che però, per
> l'umidità del luogo e l'emozione del momento, non riuscì nell'intento.
> A questo punto Pietro Micca, anziché fuggire, allontanò il compagno
> dicendogli, come riporta il Solaro della Margarita: "Togliti di lì, tu
> sei più lungo di un giorno senza pane, lascia fare a me, salvati" (in
> piemontese: *«Gavte da lì, ti 't ses pi longh ëd na giornà sensa pan»*).

Comment: Grazie del tuo contributo, @LSerni. Sentiti libero di aggiungere alla risposta le espressioni che appaiono nei commenti (vedi questo [post sul sito Meta](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1265)) perché, secondo me, la risposta sarà molto più utile se include anche espressioni che si usano.

Answer (score 0):

Parlando in modo colloquiale, informale, io direi che *il mio vicino **si è accollato** di fare questo.*
Secondo [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/accollare/) una delle accezioni del verbo **accollare** è:

> Addossare un peso, un incarico, un obbligo e similari.

Tanto per fare un esempio:

> Mi sono accollato di scrivere questa risposta pur non essendo in grado di formattarla propriamente. Il (fatto di) non sapere neanche come andare a capo è particolarmente frustrante.

In un contesto formale o per iscritto sarebbe più opportuno l'uso di una perifrasi. Ad esempio: "Io mi sono addossato il peso di scrivere questa risposta..."

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE e grazie del tuo contributo! Si potrebbe anche usare questo verbo nei contesti che ho descritto nella domanda?

Comment: Sì, si può usare in ufficio o in un negozio, ma fra colleghi. Con un cliente o un superiore è più opportuno usare un registro formale, a meno che non si abbia particolare confidenza con la persona in questione (es. il cliente è un tuo vecchio compagno di scuola). Tanto per darti una linea guida generale: diciamo che puoi usare **accollare** ogni qual volta puoi [dare del tu](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/uso-del-lei_(La-grammatica-italiana)/).

Comment: Sì, grazie, @Davide: ho capito che si tratta di registro colloquiale. Volevo semplicemente chiedere se, parlando tra amici o colleghi, potrei usare questo verbo per descrivere le situazioni della domanda. Per esempio, nella seconda situazione potrei dire a un collega "Maria si è accollata di parlare con il cliente per spiegargli cos'è successo", no?

Comment: Sì, sì, è perfettamente corretto ed opportuno. C'è da dire, però, che devi sempre specificare l'azione accollata. Ho notato che hai scritto: *si può affermare che "se come el marrón"; si potrebbe dire che "se ha comido el marrón"*. Nel nostro caso devi specificare l'azione, come in: *questo vicino "se ha comido el marrón" di dover fare questo.* La frase: *si potrebbe dire che si è accollato* non avrebbe senso compiuto.

Comment: Tuttavia, se l'azione in questione è palese, o è appena stata nominata puoi anche sottintenderla. Es. *si potrebbe dire che se l'è accollata* Dove si usa il femminile accollat**a** perché ci si riferisce all'azione/situazione accollata. Comunque grazie per il benvenuto!

Comment: Attento, @Davide: “accezione”, non *“accezzione”.

Comment: @DaG Grazie per la correzione

Comment: A me non sembra che *accollare* sia riservato a un registro colloquiale. Per esempio in ambito commerciale si usa dire "accollarsi le spese", senza alcuna remora di tono troppo familiare.

Comment: Tante grazie per questa informazione. Io ho parlato più per esperienza personale che per altro. Non avendo avuto esperienze con "accollare" in situazioni formali, né per iscritto ho deliberatamente assunto che fosse un' espressione colloquiale. Comunque vale la pena notare che anche tu parli per esperienza personale, e potrebbe essere il caso che tale espressione sia al contempo colloquiale e facente parte del linguaggio colto commerciale.

Comment: @Davide Anche a me pare che "accollarsi" sia un termine colloquiale. Trovo difficile che un negoziante dica ad un cliente che debba accollarsi le spese; è più facile che dica "le spese sono a tuo carico" (o "le spese sono a suo carico"). Se invece il negoziante parlasse di un altro negozio, potrei capire che dica, per esempio, "con loro, devi accollarti le spese di trasporto ed installazione" se volesse mettere in cattiva luce l'altro negozio (che magari è un concorrente).

Answer (score 0):

Credo che un'espressione abbastanza vicina come significato a *comerse el marrón* possa essere **mettere/porre la testa sul ceppo**.

La “testa sul ceppo” la mette chi, volontariamente o costretto dalle circostanze, è la vittima o il capro espiatorio di qualche situazione, con ovvio riferimento figurato al fatto di offrirsi alla scure del boia.

Purtroppo non trovo questa espressione su opere di consultazione standard, ma cercandola in rete se ne trova qualche esempio di uso. Per esempio, in riferimento a qualche cronaca sportiva di cui ignoro le circostanze: “Sarri, la testa sul ceppo se l'è messa da solo! A Napoli l'abbiamo sopravvalutato”. Oppure, parlando di politica: “Certo nessuno mette la testa sul ceppo del voto referendario di inizio autunno, come fece Renzi nel 2016...”.

Comment: Ho messo un bounty a questa domanda perché cercavo risposte che aggiungessero altre espressioni non presenti nell'unica risposta esistente in quel momento. Ancora non riesco a capire perché quelle che sono 
apparse nei commenti non sono raccolte in una risposta. Grazie a questa risposta, perlomeno ho potuto imparare un'espressione nuova, sulla quale non trovo informazione in rete. Anche l'altra risposta che ha ricevuto un voto è interessante, ma ho scelto questa perché mi è sembrato di capire che sia più usata.